# Composition of methods of different classes

Tags: java, methods

I have a problem applying a method from different class to the class I am writing. I try to create a class creating a box in a three dimensional sphere. I've already set up a constructor for the points in the sphere, which gets three parameters and creates a point. Here is the constructor:

```
 public Point3D(double x, double y, double z)
{
 _x = x;
 _y = y;
 _z = z;
}

public double getX()
{
return _x;
}
```

and this is the method of my current class I'm trying to use

```
public Point3D getBase() {
 return _base;
}
```

_base is a Point3D object.

```
 public Point3D getUpRightBackPoint() 
 {
     return new Point3D(getX(getBase(this)),getY(getBase(this)),getZ(getBase(this)));
 }
```

Now `getBase` is a public method returning `Point3D` object, and `getX` is a method of the class `Point3D` I've written separately and which returns double. I don't understand what am I missing here? The error says *"method getBase in class Box3D can not be applied to given types"*. Though it is a method I'm applying on a `Box3D` object.

Comment: Your `getBase` method is declared without any parameters, but yet you are passing an argument to it. Remove that!

Comment: if I use instead `getX(this.getBase())` i get an error for the `getX` which says `can not find symbol - method getX(Point3D)` , what weird is that getBase does return a `Point3D` object though...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What it tells you is that there is no `getX` method that accepts a `Point3D` object.

Comment: I think you have a mixup in your mind between *arguments* (things that come in the parentheses when you call a method), which must match the *parameters* (the list of things that come in parentheses in the method declaration), and the object reference whose method you want to invoke. You don't pass that as an argument, you append a dot and the method name to it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!! so instead of writing `getX(...)` I used `getX.this.getBase()` as both `getX` and `getBase` doesn't get any parameters (by method creation, as you said) but still I get the same error of `cannot find symbol` for the `getX` part.

Comment: No. You use `getBase().getX()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! no errors with that! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the method `getBase()` that you defined takes no argument, but when you call it you give it 'this' as argument; if you want to use `this`with the method, don't use it as an argument, but as the object owning the method:

```
this.getBase()
```

which is not necessary, just `getBase`is also fine. If you want to call another getBase method of another object, instantiate the respective object, then use it to call the method:

```
object bla = new Object();
bla.getBase(this);
```

Comment: `this.getBase()` and `getBase()` are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to be explicit, as it is needed here.

Comment: Ok, but your current phrasing suggests that `getBase()` by itself won't work and that you must use `this.getBase()`, while `getBase()` will work just fine.